# Error getting GPS location on Droid + android 2.0 sdk

Tags: android

I am trying develop an application which shows user current location. To find user's current location i am using following code:

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

private static double latitude;
private static double longitude;

public static boolean gpsAvailable = false;

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    latitude = arg0.getLatitude();
    longitude = arg0.getLongitude();
    // Log.d("MyLocationListener", "onLocationChanged");
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    // Log.d("MyLocationListener", "onProviderDisabled");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // Log.d("MyLocationListener", "onProviderEnabled");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // Log.d("MyLocationListener", "onStatusChanged called");
    if (provider.equals("gps") && status != LocationProvider.AVAILABLE) {
        gpsAvailable = false;
        // Log.d("MyLocationListener", "status NOTAVAILABLE");
    } else {
        gpsAvailable = true;
        // Log.d("MyLocationListener", "status AVAILABLE");
    }
}

public static double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public static double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

}
```

I have used this code to successfully get the GPS location on android 1.5 SDK but with 2.0 i am unable to find user's current location. I have tested this code on Droid and Magic.

Please help...